# Why am I not seeing terminal output in the Build Console for this Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm a little confused as to why I am not seeing the output from the echo() statements in the jenkinsSlack() function in this Jenkinsfile. The stages are definitely running as I can see them executing in the Pipeline visualization.

```
#!groovy


def slack_channel() {
  try { if ('' != SLACK_CHANNEL) { return SLACK_CHANNEL } }
  catch (MissingPropertyException e) { return '#nathan-webhooks' }
}


// simplify the generation of Slack notifications for start and finish of Job
def jenkinsSlack(type, channel=slack_channel()) {

  echo("echo 'In jenkinsSlack()...")
  echo("echo 'type specified as     : ${type}'")
  echo("echo 'channel specified as  : ${channel}'")

  if ( 'SUCCESS' == currentBuild.result ) {
    slackSend channel: channel, color: 'good', message: "type: ${type}"

  } else if ( 'FAILURE' == currentBuild.result ) {
    slackSend channel: channel, color: 'danger', message:"type: ${type}"

  } else {
    slackSend channel: channel, color: 'warning', message: "type: ${type}"
}

// node - action starts here
node {
  wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'XTerm', 'defaultFg': 2, 'defaultBg':1]) {

    stage ("send Slack start message") {
      checkout scm
      jenkinsSlack('start')
    }

    stage("send Slack finish message") {
      jenkinsSlack('finish')
    }

  } // AnsiColorBuildWrapper
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Echo messages are missing because `jenkinsSlack(type, channel=slack_channel())` just returns the value of `slack_channel()` without executing the method body including echo.

This is Jenkins specific problem related to CPS transform. Jenkins pipeline script is based on groovy but it has some constraints with regard to its syntax and usage. See more details here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md#technical-design

Possible workarounds below.

1.Use `@NonCPS` annotation for `slack_channel()`

```
@NonCPS
def slack_channel() {
  try { if ('' != SLACK_CHANNEL) { return SLACK_CHANNEL } }
  catch (MissingPropertyException e) { return '#nathan-webhooks' }
}
```

2.determine `SLACK_CHANNEL` in advance and pass it to the default argument `channel`:

```
def slack_channel() {
  try { if ('' != SLACK_CHANNEL) { return SLACK_CHANNEL } }
  catch (MissingPropertyException e) { return '#nathan-webhooks' }
}
SLACK_CHANNEL = slack_channel()

def jenkinsSlack(type, channel=SLACK_CHANNEL) {
    echo type
    echo channel
}
```

Comment: At first glance on the question and your answer, could be you're somehow correct about default parameter, but what about the rest? Question was about _echo_ messages missing in output. Meanwhile your explanation is definitely a mess. IMO

Comment: @agg3l echo messages are missing obviously because the method body(echo) is not executed as I wrote.

Comment: Ok, got your point. If you can explain _why_ it happens (i.e. method returns after default value evaluation, bypassing the body execution), I'll vote up your answer at least. I'm not that groovy pro and the behavior you propose seems to be strange for me at very least

Comment: From my point of view and knowledge (of Groovy), I can think of your answer in two ways - a) you're mistaken, or b) that's a specific feature of groovy I'm not aware of (which easily can be so). Detailed explanation of groovy behavior leading to such effect is very much appreciated

Comment: Okay, this was not groovy specification, but a Jenkins specific problem. I refined my answer. check it out!

Comment: @arasio Thanks for throwing in on this one. I probably should have removed the default parameter part (which I knew to *also* not be working) because I think it is distracting from the core question: "Why am I not seeing the echo() output?" Are you suggesting that the problem with the default parameter is causing the main body of the function to not execute?

Comment: I removed the code for the default parameter and, indeed, the echo()s now appear in the Build Console : https://github.com/nrvale0/jenkins-workflow-slack-test/blob/master/Jenkinsfile I'm quite surprised I didn't at least see some sort of error message before!